# Tracking User logins when utilizing basic Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I would like track user logins of our AspNetCore app that is implementing basic Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication middleware.  Our membership provider is Azure's B2C product and our app implements our configuration .

```
            // Configuration to sign-in users with Azure AD B2C
            services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAdB2C");
```

Everything I have read points to needing to extend IAuthenticationHandler interface but that seems over complicated for simply needing access to the results of the AuthenticateResult class.   Is there a more straight forward way to achieve what I'm needing or other suggested alternative?

(I recognize Azure AD B2C already tracks this information but I'm needing to connect to other system data locally which would be better suited for local app management)

I have tried accessing via the pipeline but it have been unable to find the authenticate result needed.  I have searched Stack Overflow for related question but have not found any specific to this situation.